# How to return JSON in HTML using PHP and AJAX without redirecting?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

I have searched a lot for a solution to this problem but I have not found one for it. I am trying to include a form for sending e-mails (a contact us form) on my site (using Bootstrap). PHP is being used for the mailer model.

The problem lies in the message that should appear to the user when the message is sent, the message does not appear in the place assigned to it(#status), but rather I am directed to a new page with array data.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tH8cVCWpx7pDe2OyxkGSKY6rnqV9KxlL/view?usp=sharing

Note that the message appears in all verification cases (when name or email or subject or message fields is empty), only when the email is sent, it directs me to another page!https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lK11R2a18S2arExDegcZyOnITwRlIOYh/view?usp=sharing

Here is my code:

```js
< script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" > < /script> <
  script src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" > < /script> <
  script >
  function validateForm() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Sending...";
    formData = {
      'name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
      'email': $('input[name=email]').val(),
      'subject': $('input[name=subject]').val(),
      'message': $('textarea[name=message]').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
      url: "mail.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: formData,
      dataType: "json",

      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        $('#status').text(data.message1);
        if (data.code) //If mail was sent successfully, reset the form.
          $('#contact-form').closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#status').text(jqXHR);
      }
    });

  } <
  /script>
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-8">
  <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="mail.php" method="POST">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" name="name" required="required">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email" required="required">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" id="subject" name="subject" required="required">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Message" id="message" name="message" required="required"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary ml-auto" onclick="validateForm();">Send Message</button>
    </div>
    <div class="status" id="status"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

```html
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
 $data = array();
if ($name === ''){
    $data['message1'] = 'Name cannot be empty.';
    $data['code'] = 0;
print json_encode($data);
exit();
}
if ($email === ''){
    $data['message1'] = 'Email cannot be empty.';
    $data['code'] = 0;
print json_encode($data);
exit();
} else {
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $data['message1'] = 'Email format invalid.';
    $data['code'] = 0;
print json_encode($data);
exit();
}
}
if ($subject === ''){
    $data['message1'] = 'Subject cannot be empty.';
    $data['code'] = 0;
print json_encode($data);
exit();
}
if ($message === ''){
    $data['message1'] = 'Message cannot be empty.';
    $data['code'] = 0;
print json_encode($data);
exit();
}
$content="From: $name \nEmail: $email \nMessage: $message";
$recipient = "******@gmail.com";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
$data['message1'] = 'Email successfully sent!';
    $data['code'] = 1;
print json_encode($data);
exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you experience is that upon the `form`'s submission's default behavior is the behavior you usually see when browsers are interacting with the HTTP protocol. Your `button` is of `type` `submit` and it submits the `form`.

Assuming that you handle all the logic that you want inside `validateForm`, the thing your code is missing is that your intention is to prevent the default behavior on `submit`:

```
$("#contact-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```